# Suppose $\mathbb{R}=A \cup B$ where $A$, $B$ are nonempty and $a < b$ for every $a$ and $b$.

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that there exists a unique $p \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(-\infty, p) \subseteq A$ and $(p, \infty) \subseteq B$? By “for every $a$ and $b$” I mean “for every $a$ in $A$ and every $b$ in $B.$ (There is a character limit for the title) My guess was that it has to be the case that either (i) $A=(-\infty, p)$ and $B=[p, \infty)$ or (ii) $A=(-\infty, p]$ and $B=(p, \infty)$. In either case, I was thinking $p$ should be sup$A$=inf$B$. Is that correct? And can I say $p$ is unique, because sup and inf are unique? I just don't know how to make my arguments more rigorous.

Comment: Uniqueness: Suppose $p$ and $p'$ have the property. What can you say about $\frac{p+p'}{2}$?

Comment: I'm guessing "every $a$ and $b$" was a typo for "every $a$ in $A$ and every $b$ in $B$".

Comment: @bof Yes, but that was on purpose because there is a character limit for the title of the question.